# Finding the most recent order duplicate from a customer order table - SLOW CROSS APPLY

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

I want to only show orders where the customer had an order for the same exact item, but only the most recent, completed order placed before.

I want to get the most immediate order placed for the same customer, for the same item. Like showing duplicates, but just the most recent.

**The query works fine in accomplishing what I want it to do, but when I add the cross apply to my actual query, it slows it down by a LOT.**

**EDIT: I've also tried select top 1 rather than using the row number. The rownumber line makes it only 1 second faster.**

```
declare @orders as table (
    ord_id numeric(7,0),
    customer_id numeric(4,0),
    order_time datetime,
    item_id numeric (4,0),
    status int NOT NULL
)

insert into @orders values
(1516235,5116,'06/04/2021 11:06:00', 5616, 1),
(1516236,5116,'06/03/2021 13:51:00', 5616, 1),
(1514586,5554,'06/01/2021 08:16:00', 5616, 1),
(1516288,5554,'06/01/2021 15:35:00', 5616, 1),
(1516241,5554,'06/04/2021 11:11:00', 4862, 1),
(1516778,5554,'06/04/2021 11:05:00', 4862, 2)

select distinct *
from @orders o
cross apply (
    select a.ord_id, row_number() over (partition by a.customer_id order by a.order_time) as rownum
    from @orders a 
    where a.customer_id = o.customer_id and
    a.status != 2 and
    a.item_id = o.item_id and
    a.order_time < o.order_time
)a

where a.rownum = 1
```

Is there some other way I can do this? How can I speed this up?

The previous order has to have

1. an order time before the other orders
2. the same customer record
3. the same item record
4. the most recent of all the other records before
5. a status of **not** cancelled (1 = Complete; 2 = Cancelled)

Comment: `a.status != 2` This does not match your requirement, though you state it in two conflicting ways. Either you want "completed" orders or you want "not cancelled" orders. Add another status value at some point and your current logic (and your second requirement version) falls apart. Presumably status can also be NULL - which is a yet another status value that, fortunately, is excluded by your logic.

Comment: Variable tables can only run serially. If you have a ton of data, perhaps a temp table would be a better solution? a CTE might work for you as well, as you can do the ranking right in there and select from it. a CTE would make use of the indexes in place on the source table as well

Comment: Which version of SQL Server are you using?

Comment: @Eli I'm using v18.8

Comment: @SMor in this example, there are only two and they cannot be null. I'll edit the post to reflect that.

Comment: @hanbanan . . . I cannot explain why the row number would be faster.  My guess is that the effort is the same, but the elapsed time has some randomness.  But that assumes that SQL Server does some good optimization, of moving the `where` filtering *before* the join -- something I did not realize it did.

Comment: @GordonLinoff didnt make a huge difference. i got the idea from this post if you're interested: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/273689/select-with-cross-apply-runs-slow

Comment: @hanbanan . . . That *replaces* a `cross apply` with a subquery using a window function.

Comment: @GordonLinoff yes, i repurposed it for a cross apply to see if it would change something. only one second faster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's silly.  Here's a simpler method using `cross apply`:

```
select o.*
from @orders o cross apply
     (select top (1) a.ord_id
      from @orders a 
      where a.customer_id = o.customer_id and
            a.status <> 2 and
            a.item_id = o.item_id and
            a.order_time < o.order_time
      order by a.order_time
     ) a;
```

This can use an index on `(customer_id, item_id, status, order_time)`.

Note:  If you want the most recent of the previous order, then the `order by` should use `desc`.  However, that is not how the code is phrased in the question.

And, you should be able to use window functions.  If `ord_id` increases with time:

```
min(case when status <> 2 then ord_id end) over (partition by customer_id, item_id)
```

Even if this is not true, there is a variation, but it is more complicated (i.e. requires a subquery) because of the filtering on status.

Comment: yes, i've done this initially. The row_number() line makes it 1 second faster. Still takes 25 seconds to load the query.

Comment: @Gordon Linoff in the sample data provided there are just 2 records for each customer/order permutation; where in your code do you prevent more than one previous order from showing up?

Comment: @eli . . . `select top (1)`.

Comment: @GordonLinoff the query ran about the same time with the min() stuff. I'll look into using an index. thank you

Comment: @GordonLinoff when i wrote my code, the order by was in the select statement "row_number() over (partition by a.customer_id order by a.order_time)" which ordered it by order_time, if i understand your edit right